# Golang: multidimensional string array instead of maps

Tags: arrays, string, dictionary, go

In my project I need to read a value as a global variable so I am using maps (global variable)

```
var url = make(map[string]string)
```

and I occasionally get into error `"Concurrent writes"`  as I assign value in a function (cant assign global as it gives an error non-declarative statement).

```
url["test"] = "http://google.com"
```

In PHP I could easily do this through an multidimensioanl array and read the value. Is there a way I could just use multidimensional array or maps in Go to just assign and read it in a function?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Th error is not because you have a map vs an array, it's because you have a data race. You need to protect a global map from concurrent access.

Comment: How are you calling the functions writing to the map? Some code would be helpful. Are they being called as goroutines? If so, take a look at https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex

Comment: Is there any way to declare and assign  values globally to a map??

Comment: All values required synchronization for concurrent reads and writes. A map is no different.

Answer (score 0):

The `Concurrent writes` error happens when the Go runtime detects concurrent writes to the map by different goroutines.  It is a feature added in go1.6:

https://blog.golang.org/go1.6

> The runtime has added lightweight, best-effort detection of concurrent misuse of maps. As always, if one goroutine is writing to a map, no other goroutine should be reading or writing the map concurrently. If the runtime detects this condition, it prints a diagnosis and crashes the program. The best way to find out more about the problem is to run it under the race detector, which will more reliably identify the race and give more detail.

You **can** initialize a map on a global level - see https://play.golang.org/p/AjqtQBGMEM (or below) for an example.  The same code snippet shows how maps data races can be prevented with synchronisation mechanisms - use a mutex, lock before writing to a map, and unlock afterwards.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var mu sync.Mutex
var mymap = map[string]string{"hello": "world", "foo": "bar"}

func main() {
    demo()
}

func demo() {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    mymap["hello"] = "gophers"
    fmt.Println("hello, ", mymap["hello"])  
}
```

Another way to avoid the data race is to use a channel of size 1 (non-buffered), similar to the Tour example in https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2: extract the map from the channel, write to it, and put it back to the channel.

https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html has more information about data races and the Go race detector - a very useful tool to identify hard-to-trace bugs in concurrent access.